# How can I plot a world map with some circles according to the count (n) size in few countries with leaflet in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, world-map

I apologize in advance, but I am really having a hard time trying to do a simple map plot in R using `leaflet` library. It might be the most basic question for such a simple problem, but I want to have a world map as an output with circles in those countries relative to n size. This being my input data:

```
country_groups <- structure(list(country_name = c("Australia", "Brazil", "Canada", 
"China", "Germany", "India", "Japan", "Korea, Republic of", "Romania", 
"Russian Federation", "Spain", "Taiwan, Province of China", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
"United States of America"), latitude = c(47.516231, -14.235004, 
56.130366, 35.86166, 51.165691, 20.593684, 36.204824, 35.907757, 
45.943161, 61.52401, 40.463667, 23.69781, 55.378051, 37.09024
), longitude = c(14.550072, -51.92528, -106.346771, 104.195397, 
10.451526, 78.96288, 138.252924, 127.766922, 24.96676, 105.318756, 
-3.74922, 120.960515, -3.435973, -95.712891), n = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
541L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 56L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I've tried but I get `non-numeric argument for binary operator` as an error.

```
country_groups$n <- as.integer(country_groups$n)
country_groups$longitude <- as.numeric(country_groups$longitude)
country_groups$latitude <- as.numeric(country_groups$latitude)

leaflet(country_groups)%>%
  addCircles(lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude, weight = 1,
             radius = n * 30, popup = ~country_name
  )
```

And when I try to use `as.numeric(n)` inside the graph function, it drops this out `Error in as.numeric(n) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'`

Comment: Perhaps `radius = ~n * 30` instead of `radius =  n * 30`?

Comment: Oh wow, that's what it was. Thanks!

Comment: Also try `%>% addTiles()` to plot a basemap!

Comment: @MelaniaCB No worries.